# Как получить данные из коллекции с командами discord.js?

Tags: node.js, коллекции, discord, map

Я хочу сделать команду help для своего бота, но не простую. Мне нужно из `client.commands` брать команды и из `help` брать имя, описание и как использовать, но я не понимаю как это сделать! Вот что выдает `client.commands`:

```
Collection(78) [Map] {
  '8ball' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: '8ball',
      description: 'Ask the bot a question.',
      usage: '8ball (question)'
    }
  },
  'about' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'about', description: 'About the Bot.', usage: 'about' }
  },
  'addrole' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'addrole',
      description: "Adds a role. It's that simple.",
      usage: "addrole [mention] [role name (don't mention the role)]"
    }
  },
  'advice' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'advice', description: 'Send life tips', usage: 'advice' }
  },
  'amiajoke' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'amiajoke',
      description: 'Am I a joke to you?',
      usage: 'amiajoke (w or w/o @mention)'
    }
  },
  'avatar' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'avatar',
      description: "Retrieves the user's avatar.",
      usage: 'avatar <user>'
    }
  },
  'ban' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: true, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'ban',
      description: 'bans the selected user',
      usage: 'ban [user] [explanation]'
    }
  },
  'blacklist' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 5 },
    help: {
      name: 'blacklist',
      description: 'Add the user to the blacklist.',
      usage: 'blacklist [userid]'
    }
  },
  'bug' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'bug',
      description: 'Reports an error.',
      usage: 'bug <bug>'
    }
  },
  'cat' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'cat', description: 'Sends a random cat', usage: 'cat' }
  },
  'clearwarns' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'clearwarns',
      description: 'Clear user warnings',
      usage: 'clearwarns [mention]'
    }
  },
  'coinflip' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'coinflip', description: 'Flip a coin', usage: 'coinflip' }
  },
  'coins' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'coins',
      description: "Check the user's coins.",
      usage: 'coins'
    }
  },
  'colorsearch' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'colorsearch',
      description: 'Color Search',
      usage: 'colorsearch (hexcode)'
    }
  },
  'copypasta' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'copypasta',
      description: 'Sends a random copy paste.',
      usage: 'copypasta'
    }
  },
  'credits' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'credits',
      description: 'Bot participants!',
      usage: 'credits'
    }
  },
  'currency' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'currency',
      description: 'Currency Conversion',
      usage: 'currency <amount> [Base currency] [Target currency]'
    }
  },
  'dadjoke' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'dadjoke',
      description: 'Sends a terrible dad joke that makes you cringe.',
      usage: 'dadjoke'
    }
  },
  'dog' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'dog', description: 'Sends a random dog', usage: 'dog' }
  },
  'duckduckgo' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'duckduckgo',
      description: 'Looking for something.',
      usage: 'duckduckgo <query>'
    }
  },
  'eval' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 5 },
    help: {
      name: 'eval',
      description: 'Calculates a string JS.',
      usage: 'eval'
    }
  },
  'exec' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 5 },
    help: {
      name: 'exec',
      description: 'Executes the process command.',
      usage: 'exec'
    }
  },
  'f' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'f', description: 'Press F to pay Respeсt', usage: 'f' }
  },
  'feed' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'feed', description: 'Feed someone OwO', usage: 'feed' }
  },
  'fight' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'fight',
      description: 'Fighting with the user.',
      usage: 'fight <user>'
    }
  },
  'gamble' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'gamble',
      description: 'Play for a chance to win more coins',
      usage: 'gamble <amount>'
    }
  },
  'hackban' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'hackban',
      description: 'Forced user ban.',
      usage: 'hackban [user id] [reason]'
    }
  },
  'hammer' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'hammer',
      description: 'Gives you a hammer to throw',
      usage: 'hammer'
    }
  },
  'help' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'help',
      description: 'Displays all available commands for your permission level.',
      usage: 'help [command]'
    }
  },
  'hug' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'hug', description: 'Hug someone OwO', usage: 'hug' }
  },
  'invite' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'invite',
      description: 'Link to invite the bot',
      usage: 'invite'
    }
  },
  'kick' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: true, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'kick',
      description: 'Kicks the mentioned user.',
      usage: 'kick [mention] [reason]'
    }
  },
  'kiss' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'kiss', description: 'Kissing someone OwO', usage: 'kiss' }
  },
  'kitsune' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'kitsune', description: 'Kitsune OwO', usage: 'kitsune' }
  },
  'leave' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 5 },
    help: {
      name: 'leave',
      description: 'Leave the server where the bot is located.',
      usage: 'leave'
    }
  },
  'lockdown' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'lockdown',
      description: 'This will block the channel.',
      usage: 'lockdown'
    }
  },
  'moe' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'moe',
      description: 'Sends a random image awwnime',
      usage: 'moe'
    }
  },
  'mute' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'mute',
      description: 'mute/unmute the specified user',
      usage: 'unmute/mute [mention] [reason]'
    }
  },
  'neko' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'neko',
      description: 'Sends a random Neko-chan OwO',
      usage: 'neko'
    }
  },
  'nep' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'nep',
      description: 'Sends a random NEP gif or an image.',
      usage: 'nep'
    }
  },
  'ngif' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'ngif', description: 'Neko gif OwO', usage: 'ngif' }
  },
  'owoify' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'owoify', description: 'OwO-ify message', usage: 'owoify' }
  },
  'pat' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'pat', description: 'Pat someone OwO', usage: 'pat' }
  },
  'pay' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'pay',
      description: 'Pay someone in coins.',
      usage: 'pay @user amount'
    }
  },
  'ping' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'ping',
      description: 'Ping/Pong command. I wonder what it does? /sarcasm',
      usage: 'ping'
    }
  },
  'poke' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'poke',
      description: 'Poke a finger at someone OwO',
      usage: 'poke'
    }
  },
  'profile' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'profile',
      description: 'Check lolzteam profile',
      usage: 'profile [nickname]'
    }
  },
  'purge' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 1 },
    help: {
      name: 'purge',
      description: 'Deletes X the number of messages from this channel.',
      usage: 'purge all|bots|user|author <amount>'
    }
  },
  'reload' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 5 },
    help: {
      name: 'reload',
      description: 'Reloads the batch file if it has been updated or changed.',
      usage: 'reload <commandname>'
    }
  },
  'removerole' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'removerole',
      description: "Deletes the role. It's as simple as adding a role.",
      usage: 'removerole'
    }
  },
  'rename' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'rename',
      description: 'Rename the mentioned user.',
      usage: 'rename @user|userID newname'
    }
  },
  'roll' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'roll', description: 'Rolls the die.', usage: 'roll' }
  },
  'rps' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'rps',
      description: 'Rock, Paper, Scissors.',
      usage: 'rps'
    }
  },
  'say' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'say',
      description: 'Forces the bot to repeat your message.',
      usage: 'say [message]'
    }
  },
  'serverinfo' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'serverinfo',
      description: 'Displays information about the server.',
      usage: 'serverinfo'
    }
  },
  'shibe' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'shibe',
      description: 'Sends a random shibe',
      usage: 'shibe'
    }
  },
  'slap' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'slap', description: 'Slap someone OwO', usage: 'slap' }
  },
  'smack' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'smack',
      description: 'Smack the user.',
      usage: 'smack <user>'
    }
  },
  'smug' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'smug', description: 'Smug xD', usage: 'smug' }
  },
  'softban' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: true, aliases: [], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'softban',
      description: 'Softban of the mentioned user.',
      usage: 'softban [mention] [reason]'
    }
  },
  'spank' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'spank', description: 'Spank someone xD', usage: 'spank' }
  },
  'stats' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'stats',
      description: 'Displays bot statistics.',
      usage: 'stats'
    }
  },
  'suggest' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'suggest',
      description: 'Suggest something',
      usage: 'suggest <suggestion>'
    }
  },
  'tempmute' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'tempmute',
      description: 'Temporary mut of the mentioned user',
      usage: 'tempmute @user (time)'
    }
  },
  'tickle' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'tickle',
      description: 'Tickle someone OwO',
      usage: 'tickle'
    }
  },
  'timedlockdown' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'timedlockdown',
      description: 'This will lock a channel down for the set duration, be it in hours, minutes or seconds.',
      usage: 'timedlockdown <duration>'
    }
  },
  'timer' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: { name: 'timer', description: 'Create a timer.', usage: 'timer' }
  },
  'unban' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'unban',
      description: 'Unban users.',
      usage: 'unban [mention] [reason]'
    }
  },
  'unblacklist' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 5 },
    help: {
      name: 'unblacklist',
      description: 'Remove a user from the blacklist.',
      usage: 'unblacklist [userid]'
    }
  },
  'unlockdown' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 2 },
    help: {
      name: 'unlockdown',
      description: 'Unlocks the channel.',
      usage: 'unlockdown'
    }
  },
  'uptime' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'uptime',
      description: 'Shows how long the bot has been online.',
      usage: 'uptime'
    }
  },
  'urban' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'urban',
      description: 'Search by urban to the dictionary',
      usage: 'urban <word>'
    }
  },
  'userinfo' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'userinfo',
      description: 'Displays information about the user.',
      usage: 'userinfo <@user>'
    }
  },
  'vote' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'vote',
      description: 'Vote for the post above.',
      usage: 'vote'
    }
  },
  'votekick' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'votekick',
      description: 'Vote to kick someone.',
      usage: 'votekick'
    }
  },
  'wallpaper' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'wallpaper',
      description: 'Anime Wallpaper OwO',
      usage: 'wallpaper'
    }
  },
  'warn' => {
    run: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'warn',
      description: 'Issues a warning to the specified user.',
      usage: 'warn [mention] [reason]'
    }
  },
  'warnlevel' => {
    run: [Function (anonymous)],
    conf: { enabled: true, guildOnly: false, aliases: [Array], permLevel: 0 },
    help: {
      name: 'warnlevel',
      description: 'Show how many warnings the user has',
      usage: 'warnlevel [mention]'
    }
  }
}
```

Как мне с каждой команды получить данные из `help`? Простите за тавтологию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ пришел после дня серфа интернета:

```
client.commands.forEach((cmd) => console.log(cmd.help.name + " - " + cmd.help.description)
```

Comment: Yea, discord [collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection) its like SET in javascript, and they has all array functions like forEach, map, filter